# How user could connect SysDBA?

Tags: oracle, security, audit, database-administration

We Start Oracle AUDIT and Onlogon Procedure Auditing on our Database.
We Confused, What SysDBA could connect to System. Is SysDBA Oracle User?
In SQL*Plus has a command for this acction?

Our On Logon PL/SQL code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_audit_trigger AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
...
   insert into logon_log
   (user_id       ,
     session_id    ,
     sid   ,
     serial#  ,
     host          ,
     ip_address  ,
     last_action   ,
     last_module   ,
     logon_day     ,
     logon_time    ,
     logoff_day    ,
     logoff_time   ,
     elapsed_minutes,
     elapsed_seconds)
   values(
     user,
     sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID'),
     sys_context('USERENV','SID'),
     dbms_debug_jdwp.current_session_serial,
     sys_context('USERENV','HOST'),
     sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS'),
     action_name,
     module_name,
     lo_dt,
     to_char(lo_dt, 'hh24:mi:ss'),
     null,
     null,
     null,
     null
  );
```

Select * From logon_log

```
USER_ID          SESSION_ID     SID    SERIAL#  HOST          IP_ADDRESS         LAST_MODULE      LOGON_DAY
JOHN               393900       282    1186     ERO\APPS      192.168.1.103      frmweb.exe       1/31/2013 9:27:49 AM
JOHN               393903       189    1005     ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      SQL*Plus         1/31/2013 9:28:12 AM
JOHN               393929       167    288      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      plsqldev.exe     1/31/2013 9:38:37 AM
JOHN               393930       198    858      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      plsqldev.exe     1/31/2013 9:38:37 AM
JOHN               393983       179    6066     ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      frmbld.exe       1/31/2013 9:58:21 AM
JOHN               393987       182    231      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      frmbld.exe       1/31/2013 9:59:17 AM
JOHN               393941       278    1429     ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      plsqldev.exe     1/31/2013 9:42:26 AM
JOHN               394060       305    1337     ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      plsqldev.exe     1/31/2013 10:36:34 AM
JOHN               394129       261    5236     ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      plsqldev.exe     1/31/2013 11:16:40 AM
JOHN               394196       269    783      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      SQL*Plus         1/31/2013 11:58:20 AM
JOHN               394199       309    701      ERO\APPS      192.168.1.103      frmweb.exe       1/31/2013 12:00:04 PM
JOHN               394240       196    578      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      SQL*Plus         1/31/2013 12:28:53 PM
JPHN               394243       248    702      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      frmbld.exe       1/31/2013 12:30:56 PM
SysDBA             394249       196    580      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110                       1/31/2013 12:31:56 PM
JOHN               394252       248    704      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      frmbld.exe       1/31/2013 12:32:57 PM
JOHN               394259       248    706      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      frmbld.exe       1/31/2013 12:35:29 PM
JOHN               394263       196    587      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110      SQL*Plus         1/31/2013 12:36:49 PM
SysDBA             394264       196    589      ERO\SECC      192.168.1.110                       1/31/2013 12:37:07 PM
```

Why UserID is SysDBA?

Additional Data:

```
Select * From DBA_USER

USERNAME               SysDBA
USER_ID                390
PASSWORD               BD40E271960C5535
ACCOUNT_STATUS         OPEN
LOCK_DATE   
EXPIRY_DATE 
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE     USERS
TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE   TEMP
CREATED                8/1/2012 10:28:51 AM
PROFILE                DEFAULT
INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP     DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP
EXTERNAL_NAME
```

Comment: You need to talk to your DBA/the person who installed Oracle. SYSDBA is an Oracle system user with DBA privileges. You shouldn't really be using it. I find the capitalisation of that user suspicious (i.e. it might not be SYSDBA actually). Is it rendered as SYSDBA or SysDBA in your output?

Comment: SysDBA in Output, This type of user confused us...
select * from dba_user -->
Result:
239 SysDBA 390 BD40E271960C5535 OPEN   USERS TEMP 8/1/2012 10:28:51 AM DEFAULT DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP

Comment: Is this really the same issue as [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14545620/266304)?

Comment: Maybe SysDBA created by this user?

Comment: Well found @alex; it is indeed... Mahdi, someone has created a user SysDBA. Why and who only someone in your organisation can tell.

Comment: Yes Mr.Alex, two question joined with together,

Comment: Thanks Ben, I now execute this command but have a error...?
SQL> alter user sysdba account lock;
alter user sysdba account lock
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'SYSDBA' does not exist

Comment: There is a big difference between connecting `as sysdba`, and connecting as your `SysDBA` user. User `SYSDBA` does not exist; because it's been created with mixed case (really? who thought that was a good idea?) you need to quote it when used, e.g. `alter "SysDBA" account lock`. Presumably something in your application is connecting to that account, so locking it might break things anyway.

Comment: Very Very Thanks Ben & Alex :)

Comment: @Ben - `SYSDBA` is a system privilege, not a user account; I wouldn't expect to see it (with any case!) in `dba_users`.

Comment: Sorry @Alex, you are, of course, correct. I'm going to blame lack of sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing quite what you think. You asked 'Is SysDBA Oracle User?', and the answer to that is 'No'. [`SYSDBA` is a system privilege](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba006.htm#ADMIN11048), not a [predefined user account provided by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_user_accounts.htm#BABGEGFI). Users granted that privilege can connect with administrative privileges, like:

```
connect / as sysdba
```

That is a very different thing to how your `SysDBA` user can connect:

```
connect "SysDBA"/sysdba
```

The user has been created within your database by someone in your organisation; it is not a default Oracle account, they are completely unrelated, although I suppose it's conceivable it could also have been granted `SYSDBA` privileges just to really mess with you. (And yes, that really is the password I'm afraid).

Also note that it has been created with mixed case, which means it needs to be quoted when used outside a query. You can do:

```
select * from dba_users where username = 'SysDBA';
```

... but if you aren't referring to a table column value it has to be quoted, as shown in the `connect` above and in things like `alter user`:

```
alter user "SysDBA" account lock;
```

It looks like it's probably an internal account for an application, and one that isn't setting the module (`v$session.program`?) via an [`dbms_application_info`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_appinf.htm#CHEJCFGG) call - so perhaps an in-house application. If so you might be able find out why it's there and what it's doing, and why it's been given a confusing name, but locking it might cause problems for whoever is running that application.